# add div element dynamically in same form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div element which should add itself when the image plus sign is clicked. Can someone please suggest the way to implement it? I am not experienced in web that much hence asking for suggestions/help.

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
      <div id="1"><p>
        <input name="imageField" type="image" id="imageField" src="../../../Users/user/OneDrive/Pictures/plus sign.PNG" alt="plus sign" width="20" height="20" onClick="onclickAddDiv('1')">
          <label for="select">      
         Select:</label>
        <select name="select" required="required" id="select">
          <option value="CE">CE</option>
          <option value="PE">PE</option>
        </select>
        <label for="textfield">Strike</label>
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" size="10"> 
        Price
        <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" size="8"> 
        Qt
        <input name="textfield3" type="text" form="form1" size="8"> 
        Type
        <select name="select2" id="select2">
          <option value="Buy" selected="selected">Buy</option>
          <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks a lot,
Sudip

Comment: *Where* should the div add itself?

Comment: my idea is that i want to add rows by click of plus sign, so my idea is to add the new div to existing one, future: to add a delete sign next to newly created row to delete it....not sure if this is a good design, so, looking for suggestions

Comment: @SudipM share your Javascript and CSS files.

Comment: actually, i don't have js yet, don't know if css is relevant, thanks mate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968005/how-to-add-elements-to-dom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Elements to DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968005/how-to-add-elements-to-dom)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following DOM methods

to create an element: document.**createElement**

to add the created element to a parent element: parentElement.**appendChild**

Explanation:

When you click the button you have to add an event listener with an event of type **click** and attach a function to be called with it. After that when the event is executed the associated function will run and as a corresponding result the function will execute the code which is creating an element

MDN Docs links:

to create an event listener: [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

createElement: [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

appendChild: [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Here is a snippet that will solve your issue

```js
const addElementBtn = document.querySelector("#addElement");

//Will be called when the button is created
function handleInjection() {
  generateElement("div");
}

//Create an element and append it to the form
function generateElement(element) {
  //Create an element
  const createdElement = document.createElement(element);
  
  //select the parent
  const injectInto = document.querySelector("#appendTo");
  
  //append the created element to the parent
  injectInto.appendChild(createdElement);
}

//Create an event listener
addElementBtn.addEventListener("click", handleInjection);
```

```css
div {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
}

#appendTo{
  margin-left: 10rem;
}
```

```html
   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
      <div id="1">
      <p>
        <button name="imageField" type="button" id="addElement">add element</button>
          <label for="select">      
         Select:</label>
        <select name="select" required="required" id="select">
          <option value="CE">CE</option>
          <option value="PE">PE</option>
        </select>
        <label for="textfield">Strike</label>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" size="10"> 
        Price
        <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" size="8"> 
        Qt
        <input name="textfield3" type="text" form="form1" size="8"> 
        Type
        <select name="select2" id="select2">
          <option value="Buy" selected="selected">Buy</option>
          <option value="Sell">Sell</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
    </form>
    
    <section id="appendTo"></section>
```